# Linux route command. Two gatways on the same subnet range

Tags: linux, subnet, route

I have a Linux box with two interfaces.
eth0 has ip 192.168.71.82/255.255.252.0
eth1 has ip 192.168.4.2/255.255.255.0 
I need all traffic for subnets 192.168.4.0/24 192.168.3.0/24 192.168.2.0/24 to go through eth1 and all the rest to go through eth0.
Which is the best way to do this?
route command?
Cheers for the help.

Comment: none of those work im asking the same question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614201/linux-add-static-route-simple-works-on-windows-not-on-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set routes to your desired Networks over eth1:

```
route add -net 192.168.4.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
route add -net .........
```

And then set your default gateway to whatever you need:

```
route add default dev eth0
```

(Nevertheless a route using an interface looks a bit strange to me - usually you should address the gateways using the correct router(s):

```
route add -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw <your routers IP>
```

Comment: route add -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw <your routers IP> worked like a charm. Cheers for the help.
How would I go about making the changes stick after reboot on a Debian based distro?

Comment: You can add commands in /etc/network/interfaces that should be executed after the interface is up using the keyowrkd "up" in your interface section. F.e.: "up route add -net ......."

Answer (score 1):

```
route add default gw <eth0 gateway> dev eth0
route add 192.168.4.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw <eth1 gateway> dev eth1
route add 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw <eth1 gateway> dev eth1
route add 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw <eth1 gateway> dev eth1
```

That ought to do it.